# ASP.NET MVC: Need to deploy multiple copies of a site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an app that I need to white-label and deploy for a client.  The functionality will be identical, all the pages will be nearly identical.  The only real difference will the missing logo/styling and the use of a SSO-like system instead of regular forms auth.  The authentication part is no problem, as that can just be injected.  But what's the best way for me to do different master pages / config files by site?

'Best' means least likely to cause problems and maintenance headaches.  Attributes that would be good: quick/easy to implement, quick/easy to maintain.

Comment: What does "best" mean to you? There are half a dozen ways to do this.

Comment: Well, I guess by 'best' I was meaning 'given your knowledge of the advantages and disadvantages of the various ways of accomplishing it, which one seems better than the others?'  Of course, specific situational elements could override that, but I wanted to start with some people's experience rather than trying to wade through all the options blindly.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own view engine in ASP.NET which loads a different theme depending on the customer that logs in.

This way you can load different cascading style sheets, master pages, views....etc.

About a year ago I wrote a post on this:

https://github.com/geersch/ThemedViewEngine